# What is the entry count of ELF _DYNAMIC symbol table?

Tags: c, elf

I have two uncertainties regarding `_DYNAMIC` defined in [elf(5) - Dynamic tags (Dyn)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

The symbol table received via `DT_SYMTAB` corresponds to `.dynsym` and the string table received via `DT_STRTAB` corresponds to `.dynstr`?

The symbol table entry size in bytes can be received via `DT_SYMENT`, but there is nothing written about the symbol table entry count. Is it correct to assume that symbol table size in bytes is address of string table minus address of symbol table, and therefore get the count by dividing with entry size in bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there is nothing written about the symbol table entry count.

That's because the entry count can be deduced from the hash table of symbols.

There are two common formats: `DT_HASH` and `DT_GNU_HASH` (the latter is a GNU extension). For `DT_HASH`, the number of symbols is `nchain`, which is the second word in the table. See e.g. [this](https://flapenguin.me/2017/04/24/elf-lookup-dt-hash/) document.

> Is it correct to assume that symbol table size in bytes is address of string table minus address of symbol table

*Not at all*: there is no guarantee that `.dynsym` is followed by `.dynstr`, and even when they are laid out like that, there is no guarantee that there aren't holes due to alignment.

Comment: Can you post a link with the information on the last statement, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for that link and hash hint. It is `DT_GNU_HASH` in my case. Interestingly enough the first google result for `DT_GNU_HASH` http://deroko.phearless.org/dt_gnu_hash.txt is dealing with this exact problem (I think). The calculation does not look straightforward. I'll check it tomorrow, it's too late by now.

Comment: @ezegoing Yes, the `DT_GNU_HASH` calculation is more involved than the `DT_HASH` one.